# How can I convert the solution I get from the DSolve to something I can use?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

```
s = DSolve[{δ''[t] +  g*δ[t]/l + (2*I*ω*Sin[ψ])*δ'[t] ==  0, δ[0] == a + b*I, 
       δ'[0] == 0}, δ[t], t];
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[(Tooltip[{Re[#1], Im[#1]}] &) /@ 
   Table[δ[t], {t, 0, n}], AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]], Delimiter, 
 Style["Gravity acceleration", Bold], {{g, 9.81, "g"}}, Delimiter, 
 Style["String length", Bold], {{l, 67, "l"}, 67, 67}, Delimiter, 
 Style["Initial X", Bold], {{a, 2, "a"}, 1, 3, 1}, Delimiter, 
 Style["Initial Y", Bold], {{b, 2, "b"}, 1, 3, 1}, Delimiter, 
 Style["Latitude", Bold], {{ψ, 0.855211, "ψ"}, 0, 
  Pi/2}, Delimiter, 
 Style["Earth Rotation Frequency", 
  Bold], {{ω, N[2 Pi/(24*3600)], "ω"}, 2 Pi/100, 
  N[2 Pi/(24*3600)]}, Delimiter, 
 Style["Time", Bold], {{n, 0, "Time"}, 0, 100, 1}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left, TrackedSymbols :> Manipulate, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: Code]

[image: This is manipulation]

[image: Error reported]

I think my trouble is using the solution I got from DSolve, as is underlined red. How can I make it a function?

Comment: I used many Greek  letters so I thought pictures may make it easier to read I hope that would be Ok.

Comment: Consider posting code that can be easily copied by potential helpers, instead of forcing them to retype your code just to help you.

Comment: With respect to the Greek letters: you can just replace them with the equivalent Unicode here.

Comment: As far as I can see, you never use the solution from `DSolve`! The solution itself is stored in the variable `s`. I don't see `s` in your code below the `DSolve` call.

Comment: @halirutan then how can I do that?

Comment: I tried </code>s[[1]]<code> either,it didn't work either @halirutan

Comment: try '\[Delta][t] /. s[[1]]' ,{t,0,n}

Comment: @chris It worked，thanks! It takes awful lot of time to get the graph ,though.

Answer (score 4):

You need to *look* at `s`, if you don't know in which form it is returned from `DSolve`. An easier way is to use `DSolveValue` in this case. I changed some things in your manipulate, but I'm sure you get the rest yourself:

```
s = DSolveValue[{δ''[t] + 
      g*δ[t]/l + (2*I*ω*Sin[ψ])*δ'[t] == 
     0, δ[0] == a + b*I, δ'[0] == 0}, δ[t], t];
With[{sol = s},
 Manipulate[Plot[{Re[#], Im[#]} &@sol, {t, 0, n}],
  Delimiter, Style["Gravity acceleration", Bold],
  {{g, 9.81, "g"}},
  Delimiter, Style["String length", Bold],
  {{l, 67, "l"}, 50, 70},
  Delimiter, Style["Initial X", Bold],
  {{a, 2, "a"}, 1, 3, 1},
  Delimiter, Style["Initial Y", Bold],
  {{b, 2, "b"}, 1, 3, 1},
  Delimiter, Style["Latitude", Bold],
  {{ψ, 0.855211, "ψ"}, 0, Pi/2},
  Delimiter, 
  Style["Earth Rotation Frequency", 
   Bold], {{ω, N[2 Pi/(24*3600)], "ω"}, 2 Pi/100, 
   N[2 Pi/(24*3600)]},
  Delimiter, Style["Time", Bold], {{n, 1, "Time"}, 1, 100},
  ControlPlacement -> Left]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I don't know why but it do generate a graph similar to  Sin[x],that's not what I am supposed to get! I'll check if I'd made a mistake somewhere

Comment: @SeanPatrick It's because I used `Plot` and not your code and I mentioned that *I changed some things in your manipulate, but I'm sure you get the rest yourself*. The question was about using `s` in a `Manipulate`.

Comment: orz  I ignored the changes in `s` ,I'll work on my own code tomorrow,your method seems to be faster:D